# substituting values with a sql join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two selects that I want to combine (SetA and SetB). However, for any values that are in both SetA and SetB, I only want to end up with the values from SetB. Is there a type of join I can use for this?

Comment: `select * from SetA UNION select * from SetB`, will only return unique values.

Comment: thank you jarlh, however the data is not identical

Comment: Can't you add some sample data for SetA and SetB, and the wanted result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you mean "table" not "set".  Your question is vague, but you can structure it as a query:

```
select b.*
from setB b
union all
select a.*
from setA a
where not exists (select 1 from setB b where b.col = a.col);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i said set because i am joining two queries that are similar but not identical. I'll try out your suggestion before accepting.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.column1, a.column2, b.column1, b.column2
from tableA as a, tableB as b
where a.column1 = b.column1
```

or

```
select a.column1, a.column2, b.column1, b.column2
from tableA as a 
inner join tableB as b on a.column1 = b.column1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, although this appears to be just joining the data, not excluding the entries from the first set if they are present in the second